# Confusion about derivative of $\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives, inverse-function

I was always taught that if a function's derivative is always $0$ on an interval $(a,b)$ then the function is constant on $(a,b)$. And all the information online points to that conclusion as well - in fact, it's proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425845/f-is-constant-if-derivative-equals-zero)!

Yet, when I mentioned it an a conversation with the calculus teacher at our school, he mysteriously told me to look at the function: $$f(x) = \arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})$$

And looking at it, it indeed seems to contradict this theorem. A simple application of the chain rule shows $f'(x)=0$, yet, $f(1)\neq f(-1)$.

Is this apparent contradiction a flaw in the "constant derivative theorem" or am I missing something? How could one amend the statement of the theorem to repair such contradictions?

Comment: What's $f'(0)$?

Comment: Look at the function $f=1$ when $x<0$ and $f=2$ when $x>0$

Comment: You mentioned "interval"

Answer (score 3):

The domain of $f$ is not connected, $f$ is constant on each connected component.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem is OK, it is your interval that doesn't work. The function is not defined in $0$. So, the function *will* be constant on $(-\infty, 0)$ and on $(0,+\infty)$, but those two constants need not match.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function),

$$\arctan x+\arctan\dfrac1x=\begin{cases}\arctan x+\text{arccot}x=\dfrac\pi2 &\mbox{if }x\ge0 \\\arctan x+\text{arccot}x-\pi=? & \mbox{if }x<0\end{cases} $$